# How to write the same getter and setter angular cookies for both Angular 1.3 and 1.4

Tags: angularjs, angular-cookies

I'm writing Javascript code using Angular cookies which I will be using in two applications, one of which uses Angular 1.4 so I can use the `$cookies` getter and setter objects. But in the second application I'm using version 1.3 where I cant use the getter and setter objects. How can I write simple getter and setter cookies as the same object for both the versions?

For example:

```
$cookies.getObject("user.id");

$cookies.putObject("user.id", json.data, {
                            path: '/'
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular took part a change in $cookie library from 1.3 to 1.4, so it's not possible to write same code that works in both version.

> Step 1:

Angular 1.4:

```
$cookies.putObject("key", "value"); 
var value = $cookies.getObject("key");
```

Angular 1.3:

```
$cookies.key = "value";
var value = $cookies.key;
```

or

```
var value = $cookies[key];
```

> Step 2:

If you want to write same code in both version then u have to used [Angular local storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage), and it's performance is well.

Comment: I'm looking for a generic code which I can set and get cookies for both versions, as I said I'm using single JavaScript file in both versions.. I don't think of adding a local storage is a good idea